# OOP association impliment in Code which does not violate Encapsulation

Tags: php, oop, encapsulation, ooad

this is a association scenario between driver class and car class 
driver can drive the car

- driver can accelerate the car
- driver can check is he can drive it
- driver can check is available his Driving license

class diagram

[image]

i want implement this scenario in class diagram

sample code is below

please not this is not actual code .this is dummy code

**code for class Driver**

```
Class driver {

    private $car;
    private $license
    private $name


    public __construct(Car $car,$license){       
        $this->car      = $car;
        $this->$license = $license;
    }

    //driver can accelerate car
    public accelerating(){
       $this->car->accelerate();
    }

    checkDriverlicenceIsavailable(){
        $av = ($this->license)?true:false;
        return $av;
    }

    canDriveVehicle(){
        $cd = ($this->car->$vehicleType= 'luxuary car')?true:false
        return $cd;
    }

}
```

**code for class Car**

```
Class Car {

    private $xlocation;
    private $ylocation;
    private $xspeed;
    private $yspeed;
    private $vehicleType;

    public __construct($xlocation,$ylocation,$xspeed = 0,$yspeed = 0,$vehicleType){
        $this->xlocation      = $xlocation;
        $this->ylocation      = $ylocation;
        $this->xspeed         = $xspeed;
        $this->yspeed         = $yspeed;  
        $this->vehicleType    = $vehicleType; 
    }

    public drive(){

        $this->xlocation + ($this->xspeed*(1));
        $this->ylocation + ($this->yspeed*(1));
    }


    public park(){
       $this->speed = 0;
    }


    public accelerate(){
       $this->xspeed++;
       $this->yspeed++;
    }
}
```

to show driver can accelerate the car,
 
in driver class there is `accelerating()` method and it will call car class accelerate method.
in car class `accelerate()` method only work on `xspeed`,`yspeed`

is this approach correct ?

is this approach not break the encapsulation?

if there is no need such a method in driver class to show driver can accelerate the car then how to implement driver can accelerate the car in code?

Comment: Why would a driver have a public accelerate method? Making the decision to accelerate or not is a driver's responsibility, not something another object should tell it to do. A driver's ability to accelerate should be implemented by calling a car's accelerate method when appropriate. For example, a driver might receive an instruction to drive to a given location, and based on its location and external factors like roads, traffic and environmental conditions it would then issue a sequence of accelerate() and brake() and turn() calls to the car.

Comment: are you telling is this implementation is right and to optimize it 
need to change accelerating method to private.

Comment: No, I'm telling you to consider the responsibility of each class and how your objects will collaborate to achieve a goal. Accelerate, brake and turn are what a car does when a driver sends it the right messages. Sending those messages to a car is called driving. What message would you give a driver to make him drive the car? That determines what method you need for a driver.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50897359/responsibility-of-each-class-and-how-they-interact-each-other-in-uml?noredirect=1#comment88794450_50897359

Comment: this type of another question regarding this topic 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50897359/responsibility-of-each-class-and-how-they-interact-each-other-in-uml?noredirect=1#comment88794450_50897359