# responsibility of each class and how they interact each other in UML

Tags: php, oop, uml, encapsulation, ooad

I'm trying to draw an class diagram for my project management software describing the following scenario. 
It contains

- project
- Manager
- Employee

Manager can create project
manager can change project deadline
manager can change project name
manager can assign a employee To Project (single project have only one assigned employee)
employee can submit project

For the above requirements created this Class diagram
[image]

and implement it in code using php as shown below

```
Class Manager {
private $Id;
private $name;
private $selectedProject;

public function __construct($name){
    $this->$name = $name;        
}

//manager create a project
    public function createProject(){            
        $project       = new Project('Web Dev','incomplete','2018/6/18');
        $this->selectedProject = $project;
    }

//manager can change project deadline
    public function updateProjectDeadline($projectDeadline){
        $this->selectedProject->SetProjectDeadline($projectDeadline);
    }

//manager can change project name
    public function updateProjectName($projectName){
        $this->selectedProject->SetProjectDeadline($projectName);
    }

//manager can assign a employee To Project
    public function assignEmployeeToProject(Employee $employee){
        $this->employee = $employee;
        $this->selectedProject->SetProjectEmployee($this->employee);
    }

}
```

---

```
Class Project {
    private $Id;
    private $projectName ;
    private $projectStatus ;
    private $deadline ;
    private $assignedEmployee;

    public function __construct($projectName ,$projectStatus ,$deadline ){
        $this->$projectName  = $projectName ;
        $this->$projectStatus  = $projectStatus ;
        $this->$deadline  = $deadline ;
    }

    public function SetProjectDeadline($deadline ) {
        $this->$deadline  = $deadline ;    
    }
    public function SetProjectEmployee(Employee $employee) {
        $this->$assignedEmployee = $employee;
    }
    public function setProjectStatus($projectStatus ) {
        $this->$projectStatus  = $projectStatus ;    
    }
    public function setProjectName($projectName ) {
        $this->$projectName  = $projectName ;    
    }
}
```

---

```
Class Employee {
    private $empName;
    private $assignedProject;

    public function __construct($empName){
        $this->$empName = $empName;
    }

    //employee can submit project
    public function submitProject(Project $project){
        $this->assignedProject = $project;
        $this->assignedProject->setProjectStatus('submit');
    }
}
```

I want to know  
Is my class diagram correct ? 
Is my implementation correct ?

specially implementation of below methods cover good OO Design ?

manager changing the project deadline - `updateProjectDeadline()`
manager changing project name - `updateProjectName()`

i feel code smell because in above below only thing done there is calling a setter of another class ....

P.S - another one is it bad practice class access another class setters,getters (call setter ,getter methods of one from another class)  ??

Comment: This is a bit too broad (IMHO) for SO, may be better at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Neither your class diagram nor your implementation is correct. In particular, you do not handle the assignment of employees to projects in a correct way. Your single-valued `Project`::`employee` property does not make sense.

Comment: i used assumption project can assign only a single employee only

Comment: @Susantha7: What do you intend to achieve with `$this->project = $project` in Manager::createProject and in Employee::submitProject? Neither of theses two classes have a `project `property.

Comment: @GerdWagner  added private propery project for both these classes Manager,Employee

Comment: @Susantha7: But what does it mean to assign a single project to a manager? A manager can be related to many projects as the creator/owner and you even do not have an ownership association in your model/code. We better stop this dicussion because you didn't specify clear equirements for your project.

Comment: @GerdWagner during one particular moment manager can update only a one project.that is the meaning of the assign a single project to a manager.

Answer (score 2):

In your class diagram the two things that jump out are that you have filled arrow heads (these have no meaning in UML class diagrams -- they either need to be open arrows or a closed arrow that is not filled depending on meaning -- in the diagram below I've added a *dependency* (dash line arrow) and a *basic association* (solid line arrow) which could be what you mean). In addition, the diamond in the middle -- this is not a UML class diagram element. Is it a note??

[image]

In terms of Object Orientation -- the general principles I assume you know -- encapsulation, abstraction, polymorphism etc. Typically accessor (getter) and mutator (setter) methods are a sign of OO principles being broken, as they tend to mean that another class is manipulating (or is being encouraged to manipulate) the internals of the class in question (i.e. breaks encapsulation). SetEmployee is probably more about asking the Project to allocate one -- so something like Project.Allocate (Employee) or Employee.AllocateTo (Project) might be more meaningful and less likely to encourage encapsulation to be broken.

Comment: The diamond is probably an n-ary association. Seems valid to me.

Comment: @muszeo then assignEmployeeToProject in manager class modified like below

`public function assignEmployeeToProject(Employee $employee){`
    `$this->employee = $employee;`
    `$this->project->Allocate($this->employee);`
`}`

i want to know is ok to access project class  Allocate method from manager class
is that break encapsulation or other OO good design priiciples

Comment: I think it would be fine, the consideration is that each class should be responsible for its own data and behaviour, I see no issue calling Project.Allocate(Employee) or Employee.AllocateTo(Project) from the Manager class, in both cases the classes have responsibility for their behaviour and data.

Comment: Thanks Geert, well, you learn something new each day. I've never come across the n-ary association, though it's probable I just don't remember, but good to know about it. I note it is in the UML1.1 spec so there you go...